# Finding cumulative distribution function for $\frac19(3-|x|)$

Tags: probability, density-function

$f_x = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{else } \\ \frac{1}{9}\left(3-|x|\right) & \text{ } |x| \le 3  \end{cases}$

Now I know the CDF is defined as:

$\int_\infty^af_xdx$

and I believe I need to perform the following integrals:

for $x\lt3 \rightarrow0$

$\int_{-3}^{x}f_xdx$ for $-3 \le x \lt 0$

$\int_{x}^{3}f_xdx$ for $0 \le x \le 3$

and

$\int^{\infty}_3f_x dx $

But my answers don't seem to be correct, leading me to believe that my limits of integration are incorrect, or that the absolute value plays a much bigger when integrating on each interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the CDF  $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f_t(t) dt\;$
you have 
$$F(x) = 0, \quad x\le -3$$
$$F(x)= \int_{-3}^x \frac{1}{9}(3+x)  dt= \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{3}x+ \frac{1}{18}x^2, \quad -3<x<0$$
$$F(x)= \int_{-3}^x \frac{1}{9}(3-|x|)  dt=
\int_{-3}^0 \frac{1}{9}(3+x)  dt  + \int_{0}^x \frac{1}{9}(3-x)
= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}x- \frac{1}{18}x^2,\quad 0\le x <3$$
$$F(x) = 1, \quad x\ge 3$$

Comment: Ok so I had the right idea, instead of plugging in x I'd be multiplying, raising the degree of the equation and messing everything up. Thanks for your reply! And as I thought the absolute value plays a more important part.